# Can't Open A Page on Site PHP

Tags: php

I have three pages on my site index (login page) Home (navigation) Project Creation and Management (informational) now after login there is no issues however when I try going from home to Project Creation and Management it seams like I'm instantly getting redirected back to the home page. It does the same thing via url entry or the navigation from the home page. Here's my code:

**index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
        session_start();        
        $username = "admin";
        $password = "collins1";

        if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
        session_destroy();  
        }

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        header("Location: home.php");
    }

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
        {   
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            header("Location: home.php");
        }

        else 
        {
            echo '<font color="#FF0000"><p align="center">Username or Password incorrect please try again</p></font>';
        }
    }



?>

<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Login</title>

        <link href="../CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="../CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="../JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body link="black">
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

        <div id="borderDiv">

            <div id="headerDiv">
                <p>Welcome</p>
            </div>

            <div id="subHeaderDiv">
                <p>Please login to continue to the Project Creation and Management System</p>
            </div>

            <form method="post" action="index.php">
                <div id="userNameLoginDiv">
                    <p>Username:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" size="12">
                </div>  

                <div id="userPasswordLoginDiv">
                    <p>Password:</p>
                    <input type="password" name="password" size="12">
                </div>

                <div id="loginBtnDiv">
                    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**home**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }



?>


<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="../CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="../CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="../JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body link="black">

    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

      <div id="headerDiv">
        <p>Home</p>
        </div>

        <a href="index.php?logout"><font color="#000000">Logout</font></a>

        <div id="homeBtn1"> <a href="http://collins.sulmaxmarketing.com/Project_Creation_and_Management"><img src="../button.png" alt="Project Creation and Management"></a>
            <div id="homeBtnText1">
              <a href="http://collins.sulmaxmarketing.com/Project_Creation_and_Management"><font color="#000000" ><p>Project Creation and Management<p></font></a>
            </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Project Creation and Management**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }



?>


<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="../CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="../CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script src="../JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body link="black">

    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">

      <div id="headerDiv">
        <p>Project Creation & Management</p>
        </div>
    <a href="index.php?logout"><font color="#000000">Logout</font></a>


    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You store username and password in your php template? Hands off!

Answer (score 0):

you should edit your code below

```
<?php
    session_start();        
    $username = "admin";
    $password = "collins1";

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    }

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    if ($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
    {   
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        header("Location: home.php");
    }

    else 
    {
        echo '<font color="#FF0000"><p align="center">Username or Password incorrect please try again</p></font>';
    }
}
```

?>

...

Because session_start() have to above every output-string. You printed `<!DOCTYPE html>` that make session cannot start

Comment: So I tried to move `<!DOCUMENT html>` below `?>` and still the same result?

Comment: add to above session_start() this code : ob_clean() to clean every character like blank space, utf8 BOM.... And save your file in utf8 without BOM encoding. Code after edit : `ob_clean();session_start();`

Comment: Still no joy, getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The `session_start();` must go above all else in all pages. Otherwise, the `session variables` cannot be created and saved. For that reason, the second `if` in your `Project Creation and Management` page will be called. That's the problem!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand isn't it already above everything else as its the first line under `<?php`

Comment: Yes, `<?php  session_start();  ?>`, then `<!doctype html>` ... etc

Comment: I've done this now and am still getting the same result.